# asmx to WCF or Web API

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I have an application that I'm building and for the moment, I built some web services using ASMX. In the end, the application will be deployed on azure. The web services are really simple in that all they do is call a class in the AppCode folder that handles all the work.

Is it going to be better/easier/faster/more performant to move my web services to WCF or to Web API?

Thanks for your suggestions.

PS: I want to add that the web services will need to work in HTTPS. At the moment, they're on HTTP because I'm in development mode.

Comment: I vote for ServiceStack - http://www.servicestack.net

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One-liner: if you have already got a working code and it is risky to move it to another technology stay with the working code.

**Depends who is answering.**

Web API embraces HTTP and gives you flexibilities not possible with ASMX and WCF. If you care about HTTP, content-negotiation, media types and you need your service to be called from any client (including AJAX) then Web API.

If you need to be able to use WS* security standards (e.g. using X509 certificates, ADFS, etc), possibly change your binding, serve to different clients using different bindings, extensibility, etc use WCF.

If you already have a working code, and all you care about is RPC and your clients are always going to use ASMX then stick with ASMX.

## Performance

No benchmark but my gut feeling, in descending order: Web API, ASMX, WCF

## Easier

In descending order: ASMX (since you know it), Web API, WCF

## Faster development

If you know them all, Web API and ASMX then WCF

---

*PS: it is good to pick up new technologies. The way things are going (and since you are already moving to Azure) it is important to invest on new technologies.*

Comment: Hi! The WSs are working in ASMX because they're in development. I want to move out of ASMX. Thanks for the security considerations you mentioned; I need to make them work in HTTPS.

Comment: @frenchie in this case, I would go for Web API.

Comment: ASMX service works well via HTTPS on Azure. You will just need to add endpoint and assign it with your certificate. I am not voting for using ASMX in the production, but just to let you know that it _can_ work.

Comment: @Aliostad I'm already reading your book. but a friend asked me : well I can return json also with asmx so what is the benefit of webapi besides selfhosting and content negotiation...?